# Django - Prevent a User from Accessing a Page when He/She Typed the URL

Tags: django

I have a page in Django that I don't want to be accessed by anyone except when they clicked the specific link that I made for that page.

I'm aware about @login_required but the problem is I want the page to be restricted to EVERYONE.

I haven't tried any code yet since I absolutely have no idea how to do it. Even google did not give me answer. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem a few months back and way I solved it by making a POST request.

Whenever any user clicks on the link present on-page, I make a POST request at the Django application with some verification token sent in the POST request body.

You can generate any simple token mechanism and check for token validity in Django view and if success allows users to access that page.

Comment: A user can still access page by direct link emulating `post` request

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to achieve this is to use randomized links.
In pseudo code

```
Page 1
<a href="/router/some-random-string">
```

```
# view serves '/secret-page'
class SecretView:
  def _get(request):
    # display real page here

  def get(request):
    return HttpNotFound()

# view serves '/router/<hash:str>'
class AccessorView(SecretView):
  def get(request):
    # get and validate hash
    # if valid, display secret page
    return super()._get(request)
```